# Sampling values in fragment shader from a R16_UINT-3D texture in Vulkan

Tags: c++, glsl, textures, vulkan

I am using the texture tutorial from Sascha Willems and it works without any problems. Then I change the texture from a 2D texture to a 3D texture unsigned 16 bits.

I set the correct depth and then change these values:

```
VK_FORMAT_BC3_UNORM_BLOCK -> VK_FORMAT_R16_UINT
VK_IMAGE_TYPE_2D -> VK_IMAGE_TYPE_3D
and just one component ->   view.components = { VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_R };
```

In the shader:

```
sampler2D -> sampler3D
```

But all the values I get from texture(volumeTexture, textPos).r are now zero.
What I want to do is to upload a UINT16 image but sample it as float from the fragment shader.

If I open RenderDoc the texture looks good.

pastie.org/private/i7dqw7pm0snkbf40eyywg

This is what I did in opengl:

```
  const auto& glType           = GL_SHORT;
  const auto& glFormat         = GL_LUMINANCE;
  const auto& glInternalFormat = GL_LUMINANCE16F_ARB;
  const auto& glClampMode      = GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "sample it as float"? As what *kind* of float? 16-bit IEEE-754 floats? 16-bit unsigned normalized fixed-point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is what I did in opengl:

OpenGL's [pixel transfer functionality](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Transfer) is required to accept unpleasant or slow things. Vulkan's does not.

What you did in OpenGL was force the driver to convert every pixel from a 16-bit unsigned, [normalized fixed-point value](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Normalized_Integer) to a [16-bit IEEE-754 floating-point value](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Small_Float_Formats). Almost certainly, this conversion was done on the CPU.

Vulkan doesn't have training wheels, and Vulkan drivers don't do your work for you. Vulkan has formats, and the specification states exactly what they mean. If your data does not match the format you eventually want to use, then its on you to do the conversion.

Comment: Thats explains everything, now its working. Thank you

Comment: @hidayat how did you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Can you please add some more info? By "read from texture" do you mean sampling in a fragment shader? Do you get any errors from the validation layers? Does your implementation support sampling from R16_UINT?

If RenderDoc displays your texture but it's not "visible" in your application you also may miss a proper image layout transition, at least on hardware that requires them. This also includes the correct subresourcerange.

And please take a look at the table provided at https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/xhtml/vkspec.html#resources-image-views

And make sure that your image and view parameters fit for 3D textures.

Comment: yes, sampling in the fragment shader. What I have done in opengl, is that the internal format is USHORT but the format for the texture is float. So when you sample from the texture you get float values. And I guess that what I am suppose to do here, load the image as ushort, and then in the VkImageViewCreateInfo set the format to VK_FORMAT_R16_SFLOAT

Comment: @hidayat: "*What I have done in opengl, is that the internal format is USHORT but the format for the texture is float.*" ... If you're talking about using `GL_R16` as the [OpenGL internal format](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format), the equivalent Vulkan format would be a `R16_UNORM`, not `R16_UINT`.